# How can I distinguish between WebView and native browser in client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a web application, and I want to do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (is_android_webview()) {
  // do something specific operations for android WebView
} else if (is_iphone_webview()) {
  // do something specific operations for iPhone UIWebView
} else {
  // do something
}
</script>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: do you control the webview? You could alter the userAgent string if so and use that in your if statement

Comment: @Tim In terms of iPhone v Android, aren't the two user agent values on the two platforms already different?. And even if you wanted to change the userAgent on the iPhone, are you even able to do that? I tried once, but `loadRequest` overrode my value. Unless you retrieve the html outside the UIWebView and then passed the resulting html results to the UIWebView (which would suffer from _horrible_ performance), I don't know how you could do it on the iPhone.

Comment: I have no experience with iOS, but on Android if the WebView is within your own app you can change its UserAgent string to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.
Yes, the webview which I want to change the behavior is within my own app, and changing UserAgemt seems to work for my app.
But changing UserAgent may affect other sites, doesn't it?
Should I switch the UserAgent everytime before moving?